# How to change value in getter using C#?

Tags: c#, get, set, getter-setter

So I'm trying to create a program which reads input from the user. Once the inputs are submitted, it needs to return some data but it always returns 0 for each value.

Let's say that I'm asking the user to enter 5 inputs:

`firstPaychek, secondPaycheck, finanancialAid, allowances and tips`.

I also created those variables to 0.0 since all of them are double. Here it is the setter and getter of firstPaycheck

```
private double payCheckOne = 0.0;
private double payCheckTwo = 0.0;
private double financialAid = 0.0;
private double allowance = 0.0;
private double TIPS = 0.0;

public double checkOne {
    get { return (payCheckOne / 12); }
    set { payCheckOne = value; }
}
```

Now, let' say that I would like to return the addition of every value:

```
public void getTotalIncome() {
    double totalIncome = (payCheckOne + payCheckTwo + financialAid + allowance + TIPS);
    Console.WriteLine("------------ Total Income ------------");
    Console.WriteLine(totalIncome);
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
}
```

I would like to say, that all the blocks of code above belong to an Income class. I'm trying to use them in a class called Expenses and from there I'm calling the getMonthly method in my main class.

Here it is my repl.it:
https://repl.it/@KevinAzuara/Testing

Comment: I don't really get what's your problem here

Comment: My bad, I will try to update my post. Please, take a look into my repl you will see that the values are not displayed in the output once the program finishes.

Comment: an example, if I enter 57000(from user input) as my paycheckOne it should return 4750 as the result of dividing it by 12....but it does not.

Comment: Having a property that returns a different value than the value you've set will confuse you (either now, or some time in the future). If I were you I'd include the words "annual" or "monthly" to properties to express their "unit".

Comment: No, leave the getters return the assigned values and... 1) Use the `decimal` type instead of `double` when dealing with money, 2. Do the operations in the `getTotalIncome()` method: `var totalIncome = (payCheckOne / 12) + (payCheckTwo / 12) + `.....etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you're obtaing the values from the wrong income (one that you're not setting the values for). I'd suggest you to pass in the income object instead of initializing inside the `Expenses` class. Something like this:

```
public void getMontlyExpenses(Income inc) {
    //...
}
```

And remove the declaration

```
Income inc = new Income();
```

Then you can call it like

```
exp.getMontlyExpenses(inc); // which is the right Income object
```

That's what I think your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the values on a local Income variable, but displaying them from a private member of Expenses.  You need to create a public Income on Expenses and, when prompting for the values, set the values to the public Income on Expenses.

So change

```
Income inc = new Income();
```

to be

```
public Income inc {get; set;}
```

Then in handleOption:

```
exp.inc = inc;
exp.getMontlyExpenses();
```